# Allow text to wrap without allowing other elements to wrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap 4...

https://jsfiddle.net/jfyc1ms8

```
<th scope="col">
  <a href="#">Error details</a>
  <i class="fas fa-chevron-down fa-sm"></i>
</th>
```

[image]

Is there a way, with or without flexbox, to get the chevron to align properly?

**Requirements**

- The text must be allowed to wrap
- The text shouldn't always wrap (e.g.
  flex-shrink)
- There shouldn't be more space than what is pictured
  between the "Error details" text and the chevron

Answer (score 0):

We can add some `padding` to the container to make room for the chevron, and then use `position: absolute` on the chevron,

```
<th style="position: relative; padding-right: 14px">
  <a href='#'>Invalid value</a>
  <i 
    class="fas fa-chevron-down fa-sm"
    style="position: absolute; top: 50%; margin-left: 14px; transform: translate(0, -50%)">
  </i>
</th>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/nkghjaL4/

[image]

Comment: Almost. https://imgur.com/a/mzyYZi8 >There shouldn't be more space than what is pictured between the "Error details" text and the chevron.

Comment: If you add `flex: 0` to the `<a>` tag, the chevron would move right next to it. You can use `margin-right` to push the chevron away from the text.

Comment: I tried this in my dev environment and it's causing the text to wrap: https://imgur.com/a/BYBXAse

Comment: You can use `white-space: nowrap` instead of `flex: 0` if you do not want the text to wrap. My apologies, I thought you originally wanted the text to wrap.

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect this change. You can use `margin-right` on the `<a>` tag if you would like some additional spacing between the text and the chevron.

Comment: I updated the OP so the requirements are more visible. The text should be allowed to wrap but it must not always wrap (unnecessarily).

Comment: It must be dynamic; it's a Jinja template. I'm just posting the render.

Comment: Okay, let's try a new approach using position: absolute. Please see the update.